# to create the watch for the MYSQL database selected rows updated then fired the event

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I have a requirement to monitor the Database selected rows continuously to check for the Changes(updates). If there are some changes or updates from the other sources the Event should be fired on my application (I am using a windows application in .NET). Is there any way to listen the database selected rows continuously for the changes?

if the rows are updated then event will be fired in the event it will be take the changes & write this rows into the another table.I will be used the MYSQL database table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I audit changes in a MySQL table (using MySQL 4)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218722/how-should-i-audit-changes-in-a-mysql-table-using-mysql-4)